# Generic Object Method not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

**My Extension**:

```
public class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string value, out bool hasFilter)
    {
        hasFilter = false;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            collection = collection.Where(where);
            hasFilter = true;
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

**My Code**:

```
IQueryable<GlobalLocation> customers = db.GlobalLocations;
customers.Filter(...); // Doesn't work
IQueryableExtensions.Filter<GlobalLocation>(customers, c => c.TBUID == searchTbuid, searchTbuid, out hasFilter); // Works
```

Trying to call it via `customers` doesn't even show up in intellisense. Why is this and can/how do I fix it?

Comment: Your extension class should be static I believe.

Comment: *facepalm* thank you. I do this every dang time. Check everything (or so I think) then it turns out to be the most obvious issue.

Comment: that code shouldn't compile, and the error message should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Did you not get a compile-time error for the `Filter` method? That's what I'd have expected...

Comment: I didn't try to compile, when intellisense didn't show it existed I assumed I was messing up something to do with the generics.  my bad :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
public class IQueryableExtensions
```

To:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
```

Extension methods should be static methods inside static classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place your extension method in a `static` class.

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    // Place here your extension methods.    
}
```

Exntension methods should be placed inside static classes.

One side not would be to change the name of your static class from `IQueryableExtensions` to `QueryableExtensions`, it is class an not an interface. This will not make any difference, except from making more clear that `QueryableExtensions` is a class and not an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Extension Class and method signature must be static.

use

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
```